# Emacs - noninteractive call to shell-command-on-region always deletes region?

Tags: emacs, elisp

The Emacs Help page for the function `shell-command-on-region` says (elided for space):

```
(shell-command-on-region START END COMMAND &optional OUTPUT-BUFFER
REPLACE ERROR-BUFFER DISPLAY-ERROR-BUFFER)

...
The noninteractive arguments are START, END, COMMAND,
OUTPUT-BUFFER, REPLACE, ERROR-BUFFER, and DISPLAY-ERROR-BUFFER.
...

If the optional fourth argument OUTPUT-BUFFER is non-nil,
that says to put the output in some other buffer.
If OUTPUT-BUFFER is a buffer or buffer name, put the output there.
If OUTPUT-BUFFER is not a buffer and not nil,
insert output in the current buffer.
In either case, the output is inserted after point (leaving mark after it).

If REPLACE, the optional fifth argument, is non-nil, that means insert
the output in place of text from START to END, putting point and mark
around it.
```

This isn't the clearest, but the last few sentences just quoted seem to say that if I want the output of the shell command to be inserted in the current buffer at point, leaving the other contents of the buffer intact, I should pass a non-`nil` argument for `OUTPUT-BUFFER` and `nil` for `REPLACE`.

However, if I execute this code in the `*scratch*` buffer (not the real code I'm working on, but the minimal case that demonstrates the issue):

```
(shell-command-on-region
 (point-min) (point-max) "wc" t nil)
```

the entire contents of the buffer are deleted and replaced with the output of `wc`!

Is `shell-command-on-region` broken when used non-interactively, or am I misreading the documentation?  If the latter, how could I change the code above to insert the output of `wc` at point rather than replacing the contents of the buffer?  Ideally I'd like a general solution that works not only to run a command on the entire buffer as in the minimal example (i.e., `(point-min)` through `(point-max)`), but also for the case of running a command with the region as input and then inserting the results at point without deleting the region.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### You are wrong

It is not a good idea to use an interactive command like `shell-command-on-region` in emacs lisp code. Use [`call-process-region`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Synchronous-Processes.html) instead.

### Emacs is wrong

There is a bug in `shell-command-on-region`: it does not pass the `replace` argument down to `call-process-region`; here is the fix:

```
=== modified file 'lisp/simple.el'
--- lisp/simple.el  2013-05-16 03:41:52 +0000
+++ lisp/simple.el  2013-05-23 18:44:16 +0000
@@ -2923,7 +2923,7 @@ interactively, this is t."
      (goto-char start)
      (and replace (push-mark (point) 'nomsg))
      (setq exit-status
-       (call-process-region start end shell-file-name t
+       (call-process-region start end shell-file-name replace
                     (if error-file
                     (list t error-file)
                       t)
```

I will commit it shortly.

Comment: Thanks.  I see from the docs that `call-process-region` implements a superset of `shell-command-on-region`'s functionality, so it makes sense to prefer the former.  However, if it's "not a good idea" to use `shell-command-on-region` then why is it its non-interactive form provided (and documented) at all?

Comment: There might be a situation when `shell-command-on-region` is appropriate (e.g., for shell command parsing) - but only if you know that `call-process-region` is not.

Comment: @dodgethesteamroller: Any command is automatically also a function you can call from Elisp.  There are some commands which are better never called from Elisp.  Some of those are so often misused that the byte-compiler emits a warning when it sees it.

Answer (score 2):

If you follow the link to the functions' source code, you'll quickly see that it does:

```
(if (or replace
    (and output-buffer
     (not (or (bufferp output-buffer) (stringp output-buffer)))))
```

I don't know why it does that, tho.  In any case, this is mostly meant as a command rather than a function; from Elisp I recomend you use `call-process-region` instead.

Comment: Is there a way as an Elisp newbie that I can tell if a particular function is "mostly meant as a command"?  It seems to me that if a non-interactive version of a function is documented then it should be fair game to use in non-interactive code.  Or is there some subtlety here I'm not getting?  Not trying to be snarky but genuinely curious.

Comment: @dodgethesteamroller Functions not meant to be called from Lisp are typically documented as such — see, for example, docstrings of `previous-line` or `replace-string`. Otherwise, a good indication that a function is not meant to be called from Lisp is if it sets the mark, displays a message in the echo area, or switches to a different buffer. It may still be useful to call such functions from Lisp, but only in very specific circumstances, such as when creating a trivial wrapper around the interactive function.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (emacs 24.3, don't know what version you're using), the documentation is slightly different in the optional argument:

```
Optional fourth arg OUTPUT-BUFFER specifies where to put the
command's output.  If the value is a buffer or buffer name, put
the output there.  Any other value, including nil, means to
insert the output in the current buffer.  In either case, the
output is inserted after point (leaving mark after it).
```

The code that checks whether to delete the output (current) buffer contents is the following:

```
(if (or replace
    (and output-buffer
     (not (or (bufferp output-buffer) (stringp output-buffer)))))
```

So clearly putting `t` as in your case, it is not a string or a buffer, and it is not nil, so it will replace current buffer contents with the output. However, if I try:

```
(shell-command-on-region
 (point-min) (point-max) "wc" nil nil)
```

then the buffer is not deleted, and the output put into the "*Shell Command Output*" buffer. At first sight, I'd say the function is not correctly implemented. Even the two versions of the documentation seem not to correspond with the code.

Comment: You are right.  Good catch.  The docs I quoted were from Emacs 23.2.1, but I agree that neither version agrees with the actual code behavior.  Giving the "correct" to @sds only because he is filing an actual change in the Emacs code base.

Comment: And emacs 24.4 replaces "including nil" with "excluding nil" in the documentation, because when OUTPUT-BUFFER is nil then the output is inserted NOT in the current buffer, but in "*Shell Command Output*".

Comment: Ah, perfect. This aligns the documentation with the implementation.